# Change User Agent in php.ini

Tags: php, iphone

i am trying to change user agent in php.ini file as follows.

```
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; U; 
CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OD X; en-us) 
AppleWebKit/535.17.9(KHTML, like Gecko) 
Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7Safari/6533.18.5"
```

after that when i check user agent in my php file with following command and this show that user agent has not been change.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

this shows : `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)`

which is still not iphone user agent which i have set in php.ini file.

so please help me how to set user agent in php.ini file which switch my browser request as iphone browser request.

i have also tried with following command.

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; U; 
    CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OD X; en-us) 
       AppleWebKit/535.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 
       Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5');
```

this also gives same result and i am unable to switch to iphone browser request.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the user agent setting in php.ini is what PHP sends when you make a request for a remote file over HTTP. The HTTP_USER_AGENT variable is what a client browser sends to you. If you want to change your user agent you need to get a user agent switch extension for your browser. (Firefox has one, appropriately named "UserAgentSwitcher")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you've misunderstood. The `user_agent` setting in php.ini has nothing to do with `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT]`.
The setting in php.ini is used as a default for when PHP does HTTP requests, for example with cURL.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` contains the user agent that the web browser sent along with its request to your PHP script. That's why it's showing MSIE because you're viewing the page in MSIE.

If you want to send a different user agent from your browser, you'll have to use a browser plugin unless the browser allows you to freely modify it. For example like [this](http://my.opera.com/wikipedian/blog/2011/05/18/change-user-agent-string-in-ie9).

Comment: You are correct in general, but php/cURL example is wrong. cURL takes an agent from CURLOPT_USERAGENT setting. Setting from php.ini is used in HTTP requests made with file_get_contents and such.